# Print all the rows that do and don't have blank fields into separate files

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a .csv file with col1, col2, col3, col4 and I would like to eliminate those rows that do not have any value in col4.

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
----------------------
1,    xx,  yy,  zz,
2,    aa,  bb,    ,
3,    cc,  dd,  ee,
4,    ff,  gg,    ,
5,    hh,  ii,    ,
```

I want you to return 2 files, one with:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
---------------------
1,    xx,  yy,  zz,
3,    cc,  dd,  ee,
```

and other one:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
---------------------
2,    aa,   bb,    ,
4,    ff,   gg,    ,
5,    hh,   ii,    ,
```

It would be possible to do it with some tool like awk, sed, grep ... I do not know how to do the part of printing the rows with empty column 4 or NULL.

Comment: Are those spaces or tabs in your file?

Comment: Does the file actually contain the first two rows shown "col1 col2 col3 col4" and "----------------------"? Also, is the file comma delimitated or comma tab or comma space delimitated as shown. If not, then please post an accurate representation of the actual contents of the file.

Comment: @Cyrus, if they were tabs, you could not have that alignment shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown, your data file doesn't conform to CSV rules because line 1 isn't comma-separated. If it has spaces between the commas, then you will need something more sophisticated, but if the file looks more like:

```
1,xx,yy,zz,
2,aa,bb,,
3,cc,dd,ee,
4,ff,gg,,
5,hh,ii,,
```

Then these will separate the lines as you need:

`awk -F, '{if(length($4)>0){print}}' col.csv`

`awk -F, '{if(length($4)==0){print}}' col.csv`

The first will give lines 1 and 3 and the second 2,4 and 5.

Comment: More awkishly, all you need is `awk -F, '$4!=""' col.csv` and `awk -F, '$4==""' col.csv` respectively.

Comment: Is my solution awkish, @EdMorton?

Comment: @AlexHarvey Since you asked ... :-). I'll provide feedback in a comment under it.

Answer (score 1):

This is substantially amended after errors spotted by Ed Morton.

You can do this easily using AWK:

```
awk -F' *, *' '
  $4 == "" {
    print > "FILE1.csv"
  }
  $4 != "" {
    print > "FILE2.csv"
  }
  ' FILE.csv
```

Explanation:

- `-F` sets the field separator to be commas with spaces<sup>1</sup> optionally on either side.
- When the field 4 is empty, print those lines into FILE1.csv ; and when field 4 is not empty, print those lines into FILE2.csv.

Or, more concise:

```
awk -F' *, *' '{print > ("FILE" ($4=="" ? 1 : 2) ".csv")}' FILE.csv
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that some have questioned if the OP has a tab plus comma or space plus comma delimited file. If the file contained tabs, it would display as:

```
1,  xx, yy, zz,
2,  aa, bb, ,
3,  cc, dd, ee,
4,  ff, gg, ,
5,  hh, ii, ,
```

It is visually clear to me that the OP's file is space and comma-separated, and the down-votes are not fair.

Comment: shell and awk have different semantics for `>`. In shell `>` always overwrites the previous contents of the file while in awk that just happens for the first line written to the file by the current invocation of awk and subsequent lines are appended to the file. So awk `print > file` is equivalent to shell `if (( ++cnt == 1 )); then print > file; else print >> file; fi`. So your code should be using `>`, not `>>`. In terms of style, the more awkish approach would be to use a ternary expression to avoid code duplication, so `awk '{print >> ($4==" ? "FILE1.csv" : "FILE2.csv")}' or similar.

Comment: `FPAT` (gawk only) is to describe the fields when that's easier than describing what separates the fields, `FS`(all awks)  is to describe the separators instead. So you should be setting `FS`, not `FPAT`. Using `FS="[ ,]+"` would fail if any other fields were empty or contained blanks though so `FS=" *, *"` would be more robust. If you WERE going to use FPAT then it'd be `FPAT="[^,]+"` or similar (e.g. you may or may not need to add a blank to that depending if there really are blanks around the commas and if the other fields can have blanks in between non-blank strings).

Comment: So your script written awkishly is `awk -F' *, *' '{print > ("FILE" ($4=="" ? 1 : 2) ".csv")}'` and that'd work in any awk.

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks... late here! I knew that FPAT/FS distinction and I'm confused why that even worked.

Comment: Took me a sec but - the lines that end in `,   ,` have no $4 since there's only 3 occurrences of `[ ,]+` on those lines. The other lines do have a $4 and its  `,`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `grep` to do it as well:

If you need the `colx`:

```sh
echo "col1 col2 col3 col4" > with.txt && echo "col1 col2 col3 col4" > without.txt
```

to retrieve the data and save into two files:

```sh
 grep -P "\w*?,\s*\w*?,\s*\w*?,\s*\w+," test.csv >> with.txt
 grep -P "\w*?,\s*\w*?,\s*\w*?,\s*," test.csv >> without.txt
```

note that using `>` clears the file then writes while `>>` appends.